# Grafana with Lucene - calculate percentage of representation per channel

Tags: lucene, grafana

I need to show on Grafana count of all rows and project the total in all lines:
[image]
In prtsrc I have the count of channel and need show one column with total, for example in this case:

```
Channel  Count  Total  
Bank2GO    2      7 (summarize 2+5)
Chatbot    5      7 (summarize 2+5)
```

I need to calculate percentage of representation per channel.

Comment: I have troubles understanding relation between your image and text example. Can you maybe modify it to align better?